# C# compare property type when generic is used. With Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

I have some generic class nested and I would like to retrieve with reflection the actual property type to implement some custom logic.

```
public class Base<T>
    public Base(T model)
    {
        this.model = model;
    }
    public void AMethod(){
        foreach (var property in this.model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if(property.Name = "Test") {
                ...retrieve type        }     
        }
    }
}
```

I have now a generic BaseModel with a Test property that use again the Generic type and are defined two derived class

```
BaseModel<T>
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public MyClass<T> Test {get; set;}
}

FirstModel: BaseModel<float>{}
SecondModel: BaseModel<int>{}
```

From the AMethod I would like to retrieve base on model if Test property is of type
Myclass in a generic way (if possible) and also later on which is the specific type of T to switch operations based on type (MyClass or MyClass).

---

<===========================> UPDATE <===========================>

I've just created a test case in Fiddle. The structure of the class and inheritance could be complex. The purpose is to have a simple class exposed to the user to instantiate different Objects 'Floatinputs','FloatInputsSpecial', 'IntegerInputs'. All these derives from Base where T is a specific model. This Model can have or not a Test Property of Type MyObject.
From the Base class constructor I would like to access this type.

[Fiddle test case fixed](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QismYC)

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand. You can always just call `typeof(T)` to get the type of T. And `this.model.GetType()` gets you the type of the actual instance of model (which might not be identical to the static type of T)

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you're trying to do? "to switch operations based on type" seems like something you should not be doing. That's what inheritance is for.

Comment: Also if all of your desired type parameters have to share a common base class or interface(s) you could add some generic type constraints and you can access these methods/properties without reflection.

Comment: @PMF Actually I don't want to retrieve `typeof(T)` that is my `BaseModel`, but I wuold like starting from the model instance to scan all property and for the one called Test scan the type to have some handling for example if not of type MyClass<T> throw and exception

Comment: @PMF I've just uploaded a .netfiddle example in the link. Hope this can help to understand better my question

Comment: @G.D. The problem with the test code is that `property.GetValue(this.model)` returns null, because none of your `Test` properties actually have a value. Therefore none of the if cases will ever be taken.

Comment: @PMF. You are totally right. I fixed it with some default value. Now that the example is working as expected I would like not to implement a static type for all required MyObject<int> MyObject<float>. Tomorrow I could have byte.
There is a better and cleaner way to achieve this without all these static code?

Comment: One possibility is to not use a generic in MyObject. Just change your `ValueChanged` event to take an argument of type object. But whether that's a good idea will depend on what you need to do in the callback. You didn't say that.